# 20.04 -- power settings for display -- it doesn't turn off

Tags: display, power-management, settings

I installed 20.04 and went to the settings tool for displays and set it to go blank after 5 minutes.  It never turns off.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your laptop type maybe you should remove the battery and then the AC cable from the laptop and hold the power button for 15 seconds and then power it back on.

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer! Could you elaborate why you think this would help?